# php search from mysql database showing only one page

Tags: php, mysql

The following script is showing only first page and link to next page is there but is not leading anywhere. Can someone help me?

```
$var = @$_GET['q'] ;
$trimmed = trim($var);
$limit = 10;

if ($trimmed == "")
{
    echo "<p>What are you looking for?...</p>";
    exit;
}

if (!isset($var)) 
{   
    echo "<p>We dont seem to have a search parameter!</p>";
    exit;
}

mysql_connect('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz');
mysql_select_db('yyy') or die('Unable to select database');
$query = "select * from table  where NAME like '%$trimmed%' order by NAME";
$numresults = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($numresults);

if ($numrows == 0)
{
    echo "<h4>Results</h4>";
    echo "<p>Sorry, your search: &quot;" . $trimmed . "&quot; returned zero results</p>";
    echo "<p><a href=\"http://www.google.com/search?q="
    . $trimmed . "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Look up
    " . $trimmed . " on Google\">Click here</a> to try the search on google</p>";
}

if (empty($s)) 
{
    $s = 0;
}

$query .= " limit $s,$limit";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");
echo "<p>You searched for: &quot;" . $var . "&quot;</p>";
echo "Results";
$count = 1 + $s;

while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $title = $row["NAME"];
    echo "$count.-&nbsp;$title" ;
    $count++ ;
}

$currPage = (($s/$limit) + 1);
echo "<br />";

if ($s >= 1) 
{ 
    // bypass PREV link if s is 0
    $prevs = ($s - $limit);
    print "&nbsp;<a href=\"$PHP_SELF?s=$prevs&q=$var\">&lt;&lt;
    Prev 10</a>&nbsp;";
}

$pages = intval($numrows/$limit);

if ($numrows % $limit) 
{
    $pages++;
}  

if (!((($s+$limit)/$limit) == $pages) && $pages != 1) 
{
    $news = $s + $limit;
    print "<a href=\"$PHP_SELF?s=$news&q=$var\">Next 10 &gt;&gt;</a>";
} 

$a = $s + ($limit);

if ($a > $numrows) 
{ 
    $a = $numrows; 
}

$b = $s + 1;
echo "<p>Showing results $b to $a of $numrows</p>";
```

Comment: your method of pagination is very primary. Try building classes and functions.

Comment: In addition, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. See [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: @GarrettAlbright Not if `magic_quotes` is enabled.

Comment: Is magic_quotes enabled on the host? What if they disable it? What if you decide to move to another host and forget to check that they have it enabled? It's nuts to expect magic configuration you may have no control over to make your code safe when it's really not that hard to just ensure its safety yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `$s` gets reset every time the page is reloaded or the next page link is clicked. You should have `$s = $_REQUEST['s']` at the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 0):

`PHP_SELF` is a `$_SERVER` variable. Regardless, you should use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` here.

```
echo "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?s=$news&q=$var\">Next 10 &gt;&gt;</a>";
```

Among a few notable improvements, you should really look into sanitizing the variables you put in the querystring with `urlencode()` as well.